# Add Salesforce Compact Layouts to Custom Dynamic Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, dynamic, compact-layout

We are trying to use some of the standard LEX functionality for a Custom Dynamic Lightning Component.

We have a custom lightning component where a user would choose one of 5 objects (but could end up choosing more than one object). Then there is a search box where the user searches for the records and can add multiple records (similar to how adding Campaign Members in LEX is, except that the user can choose multiple objects). We want the search options to display the Compact Layout values for each record (just like it would in standard LEX). Has someone figured out how to do this?

[image]